# web based open source solution for plot function

Tags: web-apps, javascript, html, math, self-hosted

We know there are some solutions for rendering LaTeX mathematical content on the web, for example [MathJax](http://mathjax.org). Is there a similar way (Open source library because I need to use it in an application) to create plot for mathematical formula which is written as LaTeX? For example 3D plots of ƒ(x,y) versus x,y.

Requirements:

1. It must be accessable by localhost (so self hosting must be possible)
2. Pure JavaScript
3. Understand mathematical formula which are written in LaTeX syntax (for example it must understand `x=\cos u+\frac{1}{2}` is `x = cos(u) + ½`)

Optional:

1. Symbolic computations (for example solve `\int \sin{x^2}+\sqrt{x} dx`) which helps to plot functions that are defined by `integral`, ... .

Note: I do not mean graph-theory graphs.